# failed to get text transalation

Tags: python, django, gettext

Is the following method correct to retrieve the translation text?

```
os.environ.setdefault('LANG', 'fr')
gettext.install('message', 'home\user1\locale')
print _('door')

home\user1\locale
    fr\
      LC_MESSAGES\
             message.po
             message.mo
```

Comment: I am asking which programming language it is, so that I can add appropriate tag and make your question more visible for appropriate audience. Tag "gettext" will not help you much, but "django" might (it is mentioned in your previous question). This question is viewed 8 times until now. Let's see how many views will it get after I add "django" tag.

Answer (score 0):

For example like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def my_view(request):
    output = _("Welcome to my site.")
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Read more in the [documentation about getting text translations in python code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code)